# Dosimeter in a CubeSat

Tags: payload

I heard that a *dosimeter* could be used to *detect cosmic ray particles and estimate the radiation dose received by the devices onboard*. In this way, one can determine the average amount of *ionising dose received at that specific orbit* (in the LEO).

**My question is:** How feasible is this idea as a secondary payload for an 1U CubeSar ?

Comment: Well, a TLD (thermoluminescent dosimeter) is a no-go since you can’t read it out. Perhaps look at degradation of response of specific devices. Pretty broad options with various trade offs.

Comment: As @JonCuster: suggests, how would you get data from such a device? There are different types of dosimeters, what type were you thinking of using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Geiger-Müller tube was payload of the [Explorer 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorer_1) in 1958, the first satellite launched by the United States. So yes, the idea is feasible but a little bit old. Of course you will need a radio transmitter too.

Comment: Might be fairly easy to just count output pulses and send back the total count as part of a downlink data stream. Temperature, battery status, Geiger counts, ...